# Help with Product collection filters

Tags: products, collection

I’m writing a little script to hopefully pull a collection of products which match certain criteria - so far its working at its most basic using:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

What I am struggling with is creating a filter which will only pull products into the collection if they are not assigned to any categories.

I have been tearing my hair out searching through any docs I can find but cant seem to get my head around it - I can use getAvailableInCategories() after but looping through 25,000 products is time consuming and there must be a better way to do it.

Any help appreciated - im a complete newbie smile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [monojit's answer here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/filter-product-collection-by-category#answer-7098) you'll see in order to make the collection item aware of it's category, you'll need to join in the category_product table. So your collection would look like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('null' => true));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: This worked great on 2 out of 3 test sites, but the third produced a "ERROR: Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "