# how to filter product collection by category?

Tags: category, collection

My products are in multiple categories.  As such, using

```
            ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
```

returns multiples of the same entity and therefore is unuseable.

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',array(array('finset'=>'1299'),array('finset'=>'3')))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or' => array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or' => array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                )
            )
      Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__tostring());
```

The resultant tostring looks something like:

> SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`,
>   `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `at_category_id`.`category_id`,
>   `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`,
>   `e`.`allow_open_amount`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`,
>   `e`.`email_template`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`,
>   `e`.`giftcard_amounts`, `e`.`giftcard_type`,
>   `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`gift_wrapping_available`,
>   `e`.`gift_wrapping_price`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`,
>   `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`is_redeemable`, `e`.`lifetime`,
>   `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`,
>   `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`,
>   `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`,
>   `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`open_amount_max`, `e`.`open_amount_min`,
>   `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`,
>   `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`,
>   `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`,
>   `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`,
>   `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`,
>   `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`,
>   `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`use_config_email_template`,
>   `e`.`use_config_is_redeemable`, `e`.`use_config_lifetime`,
>   `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type` FROM
>   `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`  LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product`
>   AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id) WHERE
>   (((((e.news_from_date <= '2015-02-05 23:59:59') OR (e.news_from_date
>   IS null))))) AND (((((e.news_to_date >= '2015-02-05 00:00:00') OR
>   (e.news_to_date IS null))))) AND ((`e`.`news_from_date` IS not null)
>   OR (`e`.`news_to_date` IS not null))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'category_id','finset'=>'1299')))
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or' => array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or' => array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                )
            );
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `finset`, take a look at [Filter product collection by multiple categories?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/filter-product-collection-by-category)

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                        array('finset' => '7'),
                        array('finset' => '8'))
                )
```

Comment: would finset be the category id i'm looking for?

Comment: Yes. 7 & 8 in this case are the category id you want to display

Comment: finset doesn'st seem to do much of anything in this context, check out above.

Comment: the resultant tostring is actually exactly the same as without using finset.

Comment: Excelsior!  It appears that your current representation of the use of finset is out of funk, i've fixed it.  I'll post an answer and accept yours.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498556/magento-1-7-filter-products-by-multiple-categories